# DataContext access to accdb

Tags: wpf, ms-access, visual-studio-2013

I am able to connect to an accdb (Access 2007) using WPF.  I used the info at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/92af8085-e9e7-411b-9ab0-52ae0e62942c/binding-to-data-in-an-ms-access-db-wpf-c-xaml?forum=wpf.

Given:

DataContext = (new _DbTest.DataSet1TableAdapters.PeopleTableAdapter()).GetData();

what commands let me read from and write to this accdb file?

Answer (score 0):

If that `new _DbTest.DataSet1TableAdapters.PeopleTableAdapter()` statement produces a TableAdapter, you can follow the documentation on MSDN on how to get/insert/update data.

Here is the link to the MSDN documentation:

[TableAdapter Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx.aspx)

Here is some sample code from the link on how to pull data from the TableAdapter.

```
NorthwindDataSet northwindDataSet = new NorthwindDataSet();

NorthwindDataSetTableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter customersTableAdapter = 
    new NorthwindDataSetTableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter();

customersTableAdapter.Fill(northwindDataSet.Customers);
```

You can go ahead and use the Update/Insert commands to update or insert rows in the DB. Documentation for the Insert Command can be found here:

[How to Update Data using a TableAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933.aspx)

Documentation on the Insert Command can be found here:

[How to Insert Data using a TableAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

With an Access 2007 table (CustomersTable) and two fields (CustomerID, CompanyName), the following OleDb C# code Finds, Modifies, Adds, and Deletes:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.OleDb;

string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\..\\OleDbExample.accdb";
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
//The connection is automatically closed when the code exits a "using" block.
  using (OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
  {
    try
    {
      OleDbDataReader reader;
      connection.Open();

      //Read the database
      command.CommandText = "SELECT ID, CustomerID, CompanyName FROM CustomersTable";
      reader = command.ExecuteReader();
      while (reader.Read())
      {
        string st = reader.GetInt32(0) + "  " + reader.GetInt32(1) + "  " + reader.GetString(2);
        Console.WriteLine(st);
      }
      reader.Close();

      //Add to the database
      command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CustomersTable(CustomerID, CompanyName) VALUES(?, ?)";
      command.Parameters.Clear();
      command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = 22;
      command.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "xyz3";
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();

      //Find a specific value
      command.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM CustomersTable WHERE CompanyName = @p1";
      command.Parameters.Clear();
      command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "Zap";
      reader = command.ExecuteReader();
      reader.Close();

      //Find a similar value
      command.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM CustomersTable WHERE CompanyName LIKE @p1";
      command.Parameters.Clear();
      command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "%Za%";
      reader = command.ExecuteReader();
      reader.Close();

      //Modify an entry
      command.CommandText = "UPDATE CustomersTable SET CompanyName = ? WHERE CompanyName = ?";
      command.Parameters.Clear();
      command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "xyz7"; // SET ... final value
      command.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "xyz3"; // WHERE ... initial value
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();

      //Delete row with ID = 51
      command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM CustomersTable WHERE ID = @p1";
      command.Parameters.Clear();
      command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = 51;
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();

      //Delete all rows
      command.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM CustomersTable";
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }//try
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    command.Dispose();
    connection.Dispose();
  }//using
}//using
```